# Series of Mersenne primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

If the 'Lenstra - Pomerance - Wagstaff' conjecture is true, there are infinite Mersenne primes. In this case, if we consider the series:
$$S_N=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1 }{M_k}$$
where $M_k$ is $k^{th}$ Mersenne prime, does the limit:
$$S_\infty=\lim_{N\to\infty}S_N$$ converges to a finite value?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Actually the sum over all Mersenne numbers M:k, prime or not, converges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, since
\[ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{M_k} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^k-1} < \infty. \]